# XPath - dealing with <br> tag inside <p> element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, xpath

I've got the following XPath to get the various `<p>` elements inside the div class 'article':

`//div[@class = 'article']/p`

The results are parsed like this:

```
var outPut = '<div>';
       var newContent = data.query.results.p;
             newContent.forEach(function(node, index) {
                    outPut += '<p>' + node + '</p>';
             });
```

This works fine until there is a `<br>` inside a `<p>` element.  In this case, the output of the XPath is in this form: `{"p":[{"class":"abstract","content":"text 1"}, "text2, "text3",{"br":null,"content":"text4", "text5""},"text6","text7"]}`

When this is parsed, by the code above, the content inside the curly braces with "br" (text4 and 5 in the example above) are rendered as (object, Object);

This is my first attempt at XPath, so I'm probably missing something obvious.  I can see that this part won't work: `data.query.results.p'`, as the strings in question are not in a "p" element - but I don't know whether I should be changing the XPath or just parsing the results differently.  Is there some way to construct the XPath so that the `<br>` tag is either omitted or is contained with a "p" element without creating a new node?

Thanks for any assistance.

**EDIT**
 In response to the comment below, here is more information,

This is an example of the exact response:

```
/**/jQuery1910007391897961497307_1410561766895({"query":{"count":6,"created":"2014-09-12T22:42:55Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"p":[{"class":"abstract","content":"This is the first paragraph"},"This is the second paragraph",{"br":null,"content":"This is the paragraph containing a <br> tag"},"This is the last paragraph"]}}});
```

And this is an example of how the problem paragraph appears in the HTML:

```
<p>

    Text here

    <br></br>

    More text here
</p>
```

All other paragraphs in the HTML are contained within `<p> </p>` and are parsed correctly.  The paragraph above (containing the `<br>` tag), is parsed as `(object, Object)`.

Comment: Maybe use an absolute path?

    /div[@class = 'article']/p

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON. Did you copy this part correctly?: `{"br":null,"content":"text4", "text5""}` And what are you using to perform this XPath query? XPath queries tend to return nodesets. I don't know what that data structure you have there is supposed to be.

Comment: Do you have to use xpath? The jQuery selector `$(div.article p)` should work just fine, and you can pull `.text()` from each element in the result set to get the unformatted text...

Comment: I'm trying to follow the example [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_html_scraper) to get the text from another page.

Comment: "The results are parsed like this" ... I don't see any parsing of results happening there. Do you mean the results are *processed* as shown? If not, what do you mean by "parsed"?

Comment: The XPath query returns a response as above - a node set - the node set is then processed to produce a series of <p></p> elements.  However, where a <p> element in the original HTML contains a <br>, the processing of the node set fails on that element.